# How can I cache this response from my API to prevent additional calls?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

Take the following service as an example

```
import Foundation
import PromiseKit

protocol ProfileServiceType {
    func fetchCurrentUser() -> Promise<Profile>
}

struct ProfileService: ProfileServiceType {

    private let httpClient: HTTPClientProtocol

    init(httpClient: HTTPClientProtocol) {
        self.httpClient = httpClient
    }

    func fetchCurrentUser() -> Promise<Profile> {
        return httpClient.call(endpoint: ProfilesEndpoint.byUserId, method: .get, urlParams: nil, queryParams: nil, bodyParams: nil)
    }
}
```

When I fetch for a current user, I return their profile, say for example I have multiple scenes within my app that may need some aspect of the user profile, for example their `userId`. Each time I reach out to this method it will make a network request. As this call is made when my app first starts up, I can say with some guarantee I will have fetched this data already before any other scenes or services requires it.

I was thinking something like this, but then I would need to implement a singleton pattern I believe

```
   var cachedProfile: Profile?

    func fetchCurrentUser() -> Promise<Profile> {
        return Promise<Profile> { [weak self] seal in
            return httpClient.call(endpoint: ProfilesEndpoint.byUserId, method: .get, urlParams: nil, queryParams: nil, bodyParams: nil)
                .done { (value: Profile) in
                    self?.cachedProfile = value
                    seal.fulfill(value)
                }.catch { err in
                    seal.reject(err)
            }
        }
    }
```

Recently coming from F/E development and heavily using redux, this is new to me and not something I am clear on when dealing with iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `fetchCurrentUser`, you can check to see if your `cachedProfile` is not `nil`, and then you can just return from there.

If it is `nil`, then you can proceed to make the network call. I don't think you really have to use a singleton here.

Comment: So if another scene or controller reaches out to `ProfileService` won't it be a new instance? So the value would be nil?

Comment: This actually depends upon your `ProfileService` implementation. If all the other views have their own instance, then yes, it will create new instances. But I think you can pass the same object to all the different views as well. Or you can keep the cachedProfile as `singleton`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the incoming value into UserDefaults and then return it if it exists otherwise go and for the network request and save the object.

```
func fetchCurrentUser() -> Promise<Profile> {
    return Promise<Profile> { [weak self] seal in
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedProfile"),
            let savedProfile = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Profile.self, from: data) as? Profile {
            seal.fulfill(savedProfile)
        } else {
            return httpClient.call(endpoint: ProfilesEndpoint.byUserId, method: .get, urlParams: nil, queryParams: nil, bodyParams: nil)
                .done { (value: Profile) in
                    let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: true)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "SavedProfile")
                    seal.fulfill(value)
                }.catch { err in
                    seal.reject(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that the Profile object confirms to Coding protocol.